# Passing a non-digit char after an integer to scanf

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  int n, k;
  scanf("%d %d", &n, &k);
  printf("%d %d\n", n, k);

  return 0;
}
```

In the above sample code passing to the input

`1 2`

Would produce an expected output of

`1 2`

However passing any char in-between these two digits such as

`1. 2` or `1 d 3`

Will result in a strange output of the following

`1 32766`

I would like to know why this occurs, as it was to my belief that scanf would skip over any non-digit input.

Comment: Always check the return value of `scanf` before using variables (you think) it parsed. With input `1. 2` for example parsing stops at the `.` character after reading `n`, and the second value `k` is not modified.

Comment: 32766 is oddly close to the biggest number 2 Bytes can store, I don't know if it has something to do with it

Answer (score 3):

You should check the return value of `scanf`, which tells you the number of data that are read into the passed arguments, here it is `k`.
In your case, the return value will be zero as `%d` cannot be used to read in a `char` in `C`. If the first input is a `char` it will be 0, 1 if the first value is `int` and the second value is a `char`, 2 if both of the values are `int`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n, k, rc;
    rc = scanf("%d %d", &n, &k);
    if (rc != 2) 
    {
        printf("scanf failed to set the values for n and k\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("valid input for n and k\n");
    }
    printf("%d %d\n", n, k);
    return 0;
}
```

So the `int k` is uninitialized and thus it will store some random value as `scanf` failed to set the value for this variable.

Comment: When you pass a character value to `%d` it has undefined behavior, resulted to have the value of variable `k` around `32766`

Comment: This is very helpful thank you, is there anyway to pass over the character that stops the input stream?

Comment: @dxiv updated the code to check the return value of `scanf`

Comment: `if (rc == 0)` This should be `if (rc != 2)` instead, to verify that *both* values have been read in.

Comment: yes I missed the condition, code is updated now. So if `scanf` fails to read first value it will return `0` and if fails for the second value it will return `1` and if all ok it will return `2`. Regarding the random digit stored to the variable, it could be OS dependant.

Answer (score 2):

(*Too long for a comment*.)   The following answers OP's followup question from a comment.

> *is there anyway to pass over the character that stops the input stream?*

`scanf` may not be the best or easiest way to do that, but it's still possible to do it using the `%n` format specifier which returns the offset into the original string during parsing. Following is an example, which uses `sscanf` but can be easily adapted to `scanf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void read_three_ints(const char *str) {
    int a, n1, b, n2, c;
    int ret = sscanf(str, "%d %n%d %n%d", &a, &n1, &b, &n2, &c);
    switch(ret)
    {
    case 3:
        printf("'%s': a = %d, b = %d, c = %d\n", str, a, b, c);
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("'%s': a = %d, b = %d, error parsing c = `%s`\n", str, a, b, str + n2);
        break;
    case 1:
        printf("'%s': a = %d, error parsing b = `%s`\n", str, a, str + n1);
        break;
    case 0:
        printf("'%s': error parsing a\n", str);
        break;
    default:
        printf("'%s': scanf error %d\n", str, ret);
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    read_three_ints("1 2 3");
    read_three_ints("1 2 x");
    read_three_ints("1, 2 ");
    read_three_ints(";1   ");
    read_three_ints("");
    return 0;
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/n6P3no):

```
'1 2 3': a = 1, b = 2, c = 3
'1 2 x': a = 1, b = 2, error parsing c = `x`
'1, 2 ': a = 1, error parsing b = `, 2 `
';1   ': error parsing a
'': scanf error -1
```